# Combining replacement strings and regular expressions in GNU Parallel

Tags: gnu-parallel

I have a list of file paths of the format:

```
/data/nicotine_sensi/bam/9-2_box_1_S23_starAligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam
/data/nicotine_sensi/bam/9-2_box_3_S101_starAligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam
/data/nicotine_sensi/bam/9-3_box_1_S24_starAligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam
/data/nicotine_sensi/bam/9-3_box_3_S102_starAligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam
```

I want to input into a gnu parallel command so that both the predefined replacement strings and a perl or `--plus` replacement string operate at the same time, but I couldn't find a solution in the [tutorials](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html#Replacement-strings). Ideally, `{/...}` and `{%_starAligned}` would both work together to produce:

```
9-2_box_1_S23
9-2_box_3_S101
9-3_box_1_S24
9-3_box_3_S102
```

however, the closest I get is:

```
parallel --rpl '{..} s:/data/nicotine_sensi/bam/::;s:_starAligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam::' \
  echo {..} ::: $(ls $bam_dir/*.bam)
```

which is messy and not very portable for other directories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of `{/...}` is:

```
s:.*/::; s:\.[^/.]+$::; s:\.[^/.]+$::; s:\.[^/.]+$::;
```

The definition of `{%(.*)}` is:

```
s/$$1$//;
```

So combined you could do:

```
echo /data/nicotine_sensi/bam/9-3_box_1_S24_starAligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam |
  parallel --rpl '{¤([^}]+?)} s:.*/::; s:\.[^/.]+$::; s:\.[^/.]+$::; s:\.[^/.]+$::; s/$$1$//;' echo {¤_starAligned}
```

If you know you will always remove `_something` then:

```
echo /data/nicotine_sensi/bam/9-3_box_1_S24_starAligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam |
  parallel --rpl '{¤} s:.*/::; s:\.[^/.]+$::; s:\.[^/.]+$::; s:\.[^/.]+$::; s/_[^_]+$//;' echo {¤}
```

If you will be using this a lot then putting it in a profile will probably be a good idea.